# Не изменяется ширина ячеек таблицы css

Tags: html, css, freemarker

Всем привет! Ни в какую не получается изменить ширину ячеек. Получается результат как на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно уменьшить ширину столбца кратность(чтобы он был по ширине такой же как объем), подогнать ширину столбцов дней недели соответственно под кратность и объем и увеличить ширину первых 2-х столбцов. Уже что только не пробовал, перечитал много статей, но все безуспешно. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Хочу получить вот такой результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*empty-cells: show;*/
}

.border-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td.vertical {
  text-align: left;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  width: 4%;
}

.weekday {
  width: 8%;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="table">
    <tr class="border-table">
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 20%">Наименование социальной услуги по уходу</td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 20%">Объем и периодичность социальной услуги по уходу</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="weekday">Пн</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="weekday">Вт</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="weekday">Ср</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="weekday">Чт</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="weekday">Пт</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="weekday">Сб</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="weekday">Вс</td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="vertical">Итого (в мин.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="border-table">
      <td class="vertical">Кратность</td>
      <td class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)<sup>3</sup></td>
      <td class="vertical">Кратность</td>
      <td class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</td>
      <td class="vertical">Кратность</td>
      <td class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</td>
      <td class="vertical">Кратность</td>
      <td class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</td>
      <td class="vertical">Кратность</td>
      <td class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</td>
      <td class="vertical">Кратность</td>
      <td class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</td>
      <td class="vertical">Кратность</td>
      <td class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="border-table">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="border-table">
      <td colspan="2">Итого (в минутах)</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Приложите картинку того что хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: Если тут запустить твой код - картинка получается иная, не такая как на твоей картинке...

Comment: Приложил картинку того, что хочу получить.
Не понимаю почему при запуске кода тут, получается иначе

Comment: А при чём здесь `java`?  Удаляю метку.

Answer (score 2):

Надо использовать `tbody` и `thead` тогда нормально можно задать размеры для колонок. Совет на будущее если надо фиксировать ширину колонок, то одну колонку в таблице лучше оставлять без ширины, что бы таблица могла перестроится.

```css
td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: auto;
}

.vertical {
  text-align: left;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  width: 20px;
}

.weekday {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Наименование социальной услуги по уходу</th>
      <th rowspan="2" style="width: 20%">Объем и периодичность социальной услуги по уходу</th>
      <th colspan="2" class="weekday">Пн</th>
      <th colspan="2" class="weekday">Вт</th>
      <th colspan="2" class="weekday">Ср</th>
      <th colspan="2" class="weekday">Чт</th>
      <th colspan="2" class="weekday">Пт</th>
      <th colspan="2" class="weekday">Сб</th>
      <th colspan="2" class="weekday">Вс</th>
      <th rowspan="2" class="vertical">Итого (в мин.)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="vertical">Кратность</th>
      <th class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)<sup>3</sup></th>
      <th class="vertical">Кратность</th>
      <th class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</th>
      <th class="vertical">Кратность</th>
      <th class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</th>
      <th class="vertical">Кратность</th>
      <th class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</th>
      <th class="vertical">Кратность</th>
      <th class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</th>
      <th class="vertical">Кратность</th>
      <th class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</th>
      <th class="vertical">Кратность</th>
      <th class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Итого (в минутах)</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>

  </tfoot>
</table>
```

### **UPDATE** for PDF

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.vertical {
  text-align: left;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg); 
}

.weekday {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col />
    <col style="width: 20%" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
    <col style="width: 20px" />
  </colgroup>

  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Наименование социальной услуги по уходу</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Объем и периодичность социальной услуги по уходу</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="weekday">Пн</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="weekday">Вт</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="weekday">Ср</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="weekday">Чт</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="weekday">Пт</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="weekday">Сб</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="weekday">Вс</th>
    <th rowspan="2" class="vertical">Итого (в мин.)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="vertical">Кратность</th>
    <th class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)<sup>3</sup></th>
    <th class="vertical">Кратность</th>
    <th class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</th>
    <th class="vertical">Кратность</th>
    <th class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</th>
    <th class="vertical">Кратность</th>
    <th class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</th>
    <th class="vertical">Кратность</th>
    <th class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</th>
    <th class="vertical">Кратность</th>
    <th class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</th>
    <th class="vertical">Кратность</th>
    <th class="vertical">Объем (в мин.)</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Итого (в минутах)</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Сделал по вашему примеру, текст не повернулся вообще...и ширина не изменилась

Comment: @anton_63, `<th rowspan="2">Наименование социальной услуги по уходу</th>` без **class** и **style** ?

Comment: попробую завтра еще раз, может не правильно стили прописал

Comment: неа, сделал все так же, получается вот так https://ibb.co/pd2zSX2

Comment: @anton_63, часом браузер не IE?

Comment: Chrome. Да я говорю у меня формируется pdf документ

Comment: Не помогло. https://ibb.co/YZ3yZ85
Вероятно у меня проблема в конвертировании html в pdf (использую aspose words для этого)